# Android Table (like) layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Greetings all,

I'm trying to create a specific layout that should be very simple but having a very difficult time and was wondering if I could get some pointers.

The layout I'm looking for looks like this

```
Text label   Text label   Text Label
spinner      Spinner      Edit Text
```

The text labels and spinner columns should only take about 40% of the width total, and text label and edit text should take the remaining 60%.

I tried using a table layout, but layout_weight doesn't seem to have any effect.  The only way it seems I can set width is by hard coding the width of the items (android:width).  Should I be using a table layout for this or 2 horizontal LinearLayouts?  I'm wracking my mind here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do layouts in Android. You might consider nested LinearLayouts, whose orientation can be vertical or horizontal and you can assign layout_weight attributes to each element inside them. I don't believe layout_weight is valid outside of a LinearLayout, and so the best you can do in a TableLayout is setting the gravity. If I understand your intention correctly, you might try something like this:

```
<!-- this container holds everything -->
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
  <!-- holds a text label and spinner -->
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <!-- TextView1 goes here -->
    <!-- Spinner1 goes here -->
  </LinearLayout>

  <!-- another one of the same -->
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <!-- TextView2 goes here -->
    <!-- Spinner2 goes here -->
  </LinearLayout>

  <!-- last column, with the label and edit text -->
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    >
    <!-- TextView3 goes here -->
    <!-- EditText1 goes here -->
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can find more information about LinearLayout (and RelativeLayout which is a good alternative for you) from http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks.  I'm new to Android UI design and it just seems like I use LinearLayouts for EVERYTHING and they are everywhere lol.  But I guess that's somewhat the norm.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Table Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) its basically what you needed

And quite a simple example goes [here](http://www.androidpeople.com/tag/tablelayout-example/)